# Get a string between 2 strings in php

Tags: php

I am developing a  website in php.
I want to get a sub string in between two strings
My main string is "ABCDEF\nABCDEFGH\nABCDEFGHIJ\nABCDEFGHIJKLM\n". I need to get the sub string in between last 2 \n s.(ABCDEFGHIJKLM)... Can you please help me for this issue.

Thanks
Sateesh

Answer (score 5):

```
$words = 'ABCDEF\nABCDEFGH\nABCDEFGHIJ\nABCDEFGHIJKLM\n';   
$words = explode('\n', $words);
$word = $words[count($words) - 2];
```

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/686be.php)

Comment: it doesn't matter, if you want fourth entry everytime

Comment: @gensis: But he doesn't want the fourth entry. "I need to get the __sub string in between last 2 `\n`s__."

Answer (score 2):

If the number of `\n` is unknown, you can use:

```
$string = "ABCDEF\nABCDEFGH\nABCDEFGHIJ\nABCDEFGHIJKLM\n";

$words = explode("\n", trim($string));
$last = array_pop($words);

echo $last;
```

**Question**: Do you want a newline ("\n") or literally '\n' (backslash n)?

Answer (score 2):

```
$lines = explode("\n", trim($string));
$lastLine = $lines[count($lines) - 1];
```

http://ideone.com/Qo8UY

or just (because when we trim the whitespaces away, we are looking for the last element)

```
$lastLine = end($lines);
```

http://ideone.com/DzvK6

Comment: trim does not strip last \n ;)

Comment: @genesis: Thats wrong. `var_dump(trim("abc\n"));
string(3) "abc"`

Comment: @genesis: `explode()` is executed _after_ `trim()`, not _before_. This means, that only whitespaces (including newlines), that are not at the beginning, or the end of the string, remains _before_ calling `explode()`. http://ideone.com/Qo8UY

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Split()` function to tokenise the string. You can then locate the relevant part of the string....

http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php

**NOTE**
As advised below the use of this function is no longer recomended as it has been Deprecated from the PHP spec from 5.3 onwards. The correct answer would be to use the `Explode()` function - as shown in the other answers above.

Comment: *This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.*

Comment: Ahh - apologies, i didn't realise. Noted. I will amend the answer to reflect.